# How to avoid macOS for keep asking for the passphrase for key ~/.ssh/id_rsa while remotely operating via ssh?

Tags: keychain, ssh, macos

If I remotely log on to a Mac via SSH and then use it to access another machine (such as doing a git pull) via SSH, it will keep asking me for the passphrase for key `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

If I operate on the same Mac locally using the very same user (let's say admin) it will not ask me for the passphrase if I added `UseKeychain yes` in the remote Mac's `~/.ssh/config` (I also added the same setting for the local Mac btw).

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `ssh-agent` to manage your passphrase.

This assumes you have already generated SSH keys to log into your host(s).  If not, see [How to SSH in one line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/285805/119271) for a primer on how to do this.

Next add your key to the agent

```
ssh-add
```

If it requires a passphrase, it will ask for it.  Now, every time you SSH to your remote Mac, it won't ask you for the passphrase until you kill the (local) Terminal session.  If you start a new one, it will ask once then remember it for the duration of that Terminal session.

Can you get around having to enter a passphrase at all?  Yes...

- Don't put one in.  It's asking because you created a key file *with* a passphrase.
- hard code it into a script (not advisable)

As for going from one Mac, to another and finally out to another server (i.e. GitHub), you will need to enable (set to "yes") `ForwardAgent` in both your `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`.  See [this article](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

First, Allan is right to enter "UseKeychain yes" in your .ssh/config file.
Second, my method comes also handy in another way

```
# Use Apple Keychain for ssh-key passphrases
UseKeychain yes
# automatically load keys into ssh-agent
AddKeysToAgent yes
# Automatically forward ssh-agent to destination
ForwardAgent yes
```

If you know add the key to your ssh-agent by issueing

```
ssh-add <keyfile>
```

and enter your passphrase, you can start. BUT you also add your passphrase to you keychain:

```
ssh-add --help
...
  -K          Store passphrases in your keychain.
          With -d, remove passphrases from your keychain.
```

So with

```
ssh-add -K <keyfile>
```

you not only load your key but also save the passphrase in your keychain.
You have to issue the "-K" only once.

With that configuration you have a save key and the passphrase safely stored in your keychain and whenever you open a terminal using ssh, the key is automatically loaded into you ssh-agent and the passphrase is taken from your keychain.

Comment: for me this was the trick

Comment: Best answer, ```--apple-use-keychain``` has replaced ```-K```